# circular queue: array values disappears when doubling size

Tags: java, data-structures, queue

My circular queue implementation has a problem where when I double the size of the array in the resize() method. Some values disappear.

I believe the dequeue() method has nothing to do with this.
I suspect it is something wrong with the enqueue() method or the printing methods.
I checked online for some answers but couldn't find any. Help would be appreciated since I am unable to find the problem

*CircularArrayQueue.java*

```
public class CircularArrayQueue {
    private final int CAPACITY = 10;
    private int[] data;         
    private int front = 0;      
    private int size = 0;       


    public CircularArrayQueue() {
        data = new int[CAPACITY];
    }

    public CircularArrayQueue(int capacity) {
        data = new int[capacity];
    }

    public void enqueue(int element) {
        if (size == data.length) {
            resize();
        }
        data[(front + size) % data.length] = element;
        size++;
    }

    public void resize() {
        int[] temp = data;
        int currentLength = data.length;
        data = new int[2*currentLength];
        System.arraycopy(temp, 0, data, 0, currentLength);
    }

    public int dequeue() {
        if (size == 0) 
            return Integer.MIN_VALUE;

        int temp = data[front];
        data[front] = 0;
        front = (front + 1) % data.length;
        size--;
        return temp;
    }

    public int peek() {
        if (size == 0) 
            return Integer.MIN_VALUE;

        return data[front];
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return size==0;
    }

    public void printQueue() {
        if(size == 0) {
            System.out.println("Queue is EMPTY!");
        }else {
            System.out.print("Queue: ");
            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                System.out.print(data[(i+front)%data.length]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

    public void printArray() {
        System.out.print("Array: ");
        for(int i : data) {
            System.out.print(i+" ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

*MainCircularArrayQueue.java*

```
public class MainCircularArrayQueue {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CircularArrayQueue queue = new CircularArrayQueue(3);
        System.out.println("Add 3 elements");
        queue.enqueue(11);
        queue.enqueue(22);
        queue.enqueue(33);
        queue.printQueue();
        queue.printArray();
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Remove 1 element");
        System.out.println("Remove: " + queue.dequeue());
        queue.printQueue();
        queue.printArray();
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Add 1 more element");
        queue.enqueue(44);
        queue.printQueue();
        queue.printArray();
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Add 1 more element");
        queue.enqueue(55);
        queue.printQueue();
        queue.printArray();
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Remove 1 element");
        System.out.println("Remove: " + queue.dequeue());
        queue.printQueue();
        queue.printArray();
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Add 4 more elements");
        queue.enqueue(66);
        queue.enqueue(77);
        queue.enqueue(88);
        queue.enqueue(99);
        queue.printQueue();
        queue.printArray();
    }
}
```

**Expected Results**

```
Add 3 elements
Queue: 11 22 33 
Array: 11 22 33 

Remove 1 element
Remove: 11
Queue: 22 33 
Array: 0 22 33 

Add 1 more element
Queue: 22 33 44 
Array: 44 22 33 

Add 1 more element
Queue: 22 33 44 55 
Array: 22 33 44 55 0 0 

Remove 1 element
Remove: 22
Queue: 33 44 55 
Array: 0 33 44 55 0 0 

Add 4 more elements
Queue: 33 44 55 66 77 88 99 
Array: 33 44 55 66 77 88 99 0 0 0 0 0
```

**Actual output:**

```
Add 3 elements
Queue: 11 22 33
Array: 11 22 33

Remove 1 element
Remove: 11
Queue: 22 33
Array: 0 22 33

Add 1 more element
Queue: 22 33 44
Array: 44 22 33

Add 1 more element
Queue: 22 33 0 55
Array: 44 22 33 0 55 0

Remove 1 element
Remove: 22
Queue: 33 0 55
Array: 44 0 33 0 55 0

Add 4 more elements
Queue: 33 0 55 66 0 0 99
Array: 77 88 33 0 55 66 0 0 99 0 0 0
```

Comment: Please keep the amount of code in questions to a minimum unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to keep track of `rear`.

```
class CircularArrayQueue {
    private final int CAPACITY = 10;
    private int[] data;         
    private int front = 0;   
    private int rear = 0;
    private int size = 0;       


    public CircularArrayQueue() {
        data = new int[CAPACITY];
    }

    public CircularArrayQueue(int capacity) {
        data = new int[capacity];
    }

    public void enqueue(int element) {
        if (size == data.length) {
            resize();
        }
        data[rear] = element;
        rear = (rear + 1) % data.length;
        size++;
    }

    public void resize() {
        int[] temp = data;
        int currentLength = data.length;
        data = new int[2*currentLength];

        for (int i = 0; i < currentLength; i++) {
            data[i] = temp[(i + front) % currentLength];
        }

        front = 0;
        rear = currentLength;
    }

    public int dequeue() {
        if (size == 0) 
            return Integer.MIN_VALUE;

        int temp = data[front];
        data[front] = 0;
        front = (front + 1) % data.length;
        size--;
        return temp;
    }

    public int peek() {
        if (size == 0) 
            return Integer.MIN_VALUE;

        return data[front];
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return size==0;
    }

    public void printQueue() {
        if(size == 0) {
            System.out.println("Queue is EMPTY!");
        }else {
            System.out.print("Queue: ");
            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                System.out.print(data[(i+front)%data.length]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

    public void printArray() {
        System.out.print("Array: ");
        for(int i : data) {
            System.out.print(i+" ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not necessarily with `enqueue()` or `dequeue()`. What's happening is that when the buffer gets automatically resized, it changes the order of the elements in the queue.
When the array is `[44 22 33]`, `front` is at index 1 and the "rear position" is defined as being `size` indices in front of that, wrapping around to be at index 1 as well. Adding the next number triggers the array to be resized, forming `[44 22 33 0 0 0]`. `55` is added at index 4 because because the "rear position" calculation no longer wraps around the end of the array. Mokarrom Hossain's code sample above should work, though, because he modified `resize()` to copy the numbers from the original array to the resized array in the order that they were queued.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it. I got it now!